# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_rgb'

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I wrote a simple code to form taylor digram using skillmetrics package. I used python version Python 2.7.12. The code is as follows:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import skill_metrics as sm
fire=pd.read_csv('fire.csv')
PMfire = zip(fire['Date'],fire['PM_fire'],fire['Embassy_PM'])
#taylor_stats1 = sm.taylor_statistics('PM_fire','Embassy_PM','Date')
o= {"Data":fire['Embassy_PM'],'Date':fire['Date']}# form date and and embassy datas
p= {"Data":fire['PM_fire'],'Date':fire['Date']}# form  dictionary containg pm_fire and date
# Calculate statistics for Taylor diagram
    # The first array element corresponds to the reference series 
    # for the while the second is that for the predicted series.
taylor_stats1 = sm.taylor_statistics(p,o,'Data')
sdev = np.array([taylor_stats1['sdev'][0]])# Calculate standard deviation
crmsd = np.array([taylor_stats1['crmsd'][0]])#Calculate root mean square difference
ccoef = np.array([taylor_stats1['ccoef'][0]])# Calculate correlation coefficient
sm.taylor_diagram(sdev,crmsd,ccoef)#form taylor digram
plt.savefig('taylor.png')
plt.show()
```

But, it is giving me error.The error is as follows:-

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-edf3b67792d8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/mala/Downloads/F/taylor_plot.py', wdir='/home/mala/Downloads/F')

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/mala/Downloads/F/taylor_plot.py", line 21, in <module>
    sm.taylor_diagram(sdev,crmsd,ccoef)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skill_metrics/taylor_diagram.py", line 110, in taylor_diagram
    plot_pattern_diagram_markers(X,Y,option)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skill_metrics/plot_pattern_diagram_markers.py", line 104, in plot_pattern_diagram_markers
    rgba = clr.to_rgb(option['markercolor']) + (alpha,)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_rgb'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `to_rgb` function was added relatively recently to the `matplotlib.colors` namespace. You probably have an older version of matplotlib installed. Try updating to the latest version of matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks the error stopped comming.But now I am getting another error `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,)`

Comment: Please ask a new question. Also in general for Python errors you should always include both the full traceback and the error you see, since the traceback gives the context for where the error comes from.

Comment: Can anyone that has solved this comment on the required version of matplotlib? I have matplotlib.__version__ == '1.5.1' and get this error for python 2.7

Comment: I think matplotlib 2.0 or newer should have it.

Comment: I tried to do `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` . Now if I check with `pip show matplotlib` I have `Version: 2.2.5` . However, I still have the same error in my Jupiter notebook working with a kernel in a virtualenvironment.

Comment: I think I found my problem, when I do `print matplotlib.__version__` in my jupyter notebook I get the version `1.5.1`. So it means that my Jupyter notebook still sees an old version of the library

Answer (score 3):

That's related to the versions of the two tool libraries that ipykernel and matplotlib are not compatible. [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_rgba'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272404/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-to-rgba/53536864#53536864)

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading matplotlib and numpy to the latest version

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade numpy
sudo pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Answer (score -2):

Just run the command below it will solve the issue

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so that others will understand more easy way

Comment: Just run the command------------> sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib

Comment: Reading this post: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

It seems that you should NEVER install any package with `sudo pip install`