# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_rgba'

Tags: matplotlib

I got error when I used matplotlib.pyplot to show image

```
      5 plt.ylim(-5,6)
      6 plt.title('Question 1(c): sample cluster data (10,000 points per cluster)')
----> 7 plt.show()

C:\Users\yashi\Anaconda3\envs\CSC411\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in show(*args, **kw)
    242     In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until
    243     the figures have been closed; in interactive mode it has no
--> 244     effect unless figures were created prior to a change from
    245     non-interactive to interactive mode (not recommended).  In
    246     that case it displays the figures but does not block.

C:\Users\yashi\Anaconda3\envs\CSC411\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\pylab\backend_inline.pyc in show(close, block)
     37             display(
     38                 figure_manager.canvas.figure,
---> 39                 metadata=_fetch_figure_metadata(figure_manager.canvas.figure)
     40             )
     41     finally:

C:\Users\yashi\Anaconda3\envs\CSC411\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\pylab\backend_inline.pyc in _fetch_figure_metadata(fig)
    172     """Get some metadata to help with displaying a figure."""
    173     # determine if a background is needed for legibility
--> 174     if _is_transparent(fig.get_facecolor()):
    175         # the background is transparent
    176         ticksLight = _is_light([label.get_color()

C:\Users\yashi\Anaconda3\envs\CSC411\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\pylab\backend_inline.pyc in _is_transparent(color)
    193 def _is_transparent(color):
    194     """Determine transparency from alpha."""
--> 195     rgba = colors.to_rgba(color)
    196     return rgba[3] < .5

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_rgba'
```

According to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492556/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-to-rgb),

I updated matplotlib to 2.23 but it still doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Feel free to provide a [mcve] of the issue. Add `print(matplotlib.__version__)` to it to see if 2.2.3 is really used.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, it is 2.23

Comment: If you want someone to find out what's wrong you should be a little more cooperative. The information you provide simply does not suffice to find out anything about the problem. You need a  [mcve] that other people can run and you need to state how you run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this situation,that caused by ipykernel versions. I change ipykernel from 4.10.0 to 4.9.0.The problem can be solved.

Comment: How do you chage the ipykernel version as you have mentioned above? Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Use pip like `pip install ipykernel=4.9.0`

Comment: does not work on me. using windows 10 here. already did all suggestion no luck also restarting my pc

Answer (score 1):

Run the command line on your windows / terminal on Mac and perform

```
conda install ipykernel=4.9.0
```

Comment: I had to go back to 4.8.0, for it to work with matplotlib 1.5.3. ipykernel 4.9.0 still gave the error on a missing to_rgba()