# Spyder stopped working after Anaconda matplotlib upgrade

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

**Answer to question:**
What is described under "edit" made Spyder and Matplotlib work.

Spyder won't launch anymore.
I use windows and Anaconda.
Here's what's happened:

1) When Spyder worked, matplotlib did not work.
When trying to plot something I got the error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_rgba'
```

2) Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47492556/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-to-rgb) thread, I upgraded matplotlib by

```
conda upgrade matplotlib
```

Spyder would still not work. Among the error messages I got when trying to launch Spyder from the windows terminal was

```
"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PLUGIN_CLASS'
```

and

```
raise PythonQtErrpr('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

3) I then did

```
conda update qt pyqt
```

which gave the last error of 2) when trying to launce Spyder.

4) I den did

```
conda install --force-reinstall pyqt qt
```

which also gave the last error of 2) when trying to launce Spyder.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**edit:** 
I am not sure why, but I just discovered by running

```
python --version
```

that it is Python 2.7.15 and not Python 3 that is installed. However, I am pretty sure I was using Python3, since the print commands I was using was of the Python3 type. I will now try

```
conda update conda
conda install python=3.7.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The folowing fixed the problem and made Spyder and Matplotlib work

```
conda update conda
conda install python=3.7.2
```